# scrape a site that uses cookies and fids

Tags: node.js, cookies, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [this site](https://www2.fdic.gov/sod/sodSummary.asp?barItem=3).  If you click `county` and then `continue` (select a state and/or year if you like), you'll get a table.  However, the site is using cookies and hidden fields such as `as_sfid` and `as_fid` that makes this less than straight forward.  I'm using the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) and as far as I can tell I am capturing the cookies and the needed formData for the second request but the html I get is an error page that says the "Object Moved".  If you look at the requests made by your browser, you'll see another get request is made that receives no response.  I tried sticking that in between the two current requests just incase but it didn't change anything.

```
var util        = require('util');
var debug       = require('debug')('app');
var _           = require('lodash');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var $           = require('cheerio');
var request     = require("request");
request         = request.defaults({ jar: true });
var j           = request.jar();

var inspect = _.partialRight(util.inspect, false, null)

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        debug(err);
    } else {
        var collection = db.collection('FDIC');
        var getUrl = 'https://www2.fdic.gov/sod/sodSummary.asp?barItem=3';
        request.get({ url: getUrl, jar: j }, function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
               debug('err:', err);
            } else {
                $ = $.load(res.body.toString());
                var sfid = $("input[name='as_sfid']")['0'].attribs.value;
                var fid = $("input[name='as_fid']")['0'].attribs.value;
                var formData = {
                    sInfoAsOf: "2014",
                    barItem: 3,
                    sSummaryList: 8,
                    as_sfid: sfid,
                    as_fid: fid
                };
                debug('formData:', formData)
                debug('cookies:', j.getCookies(getUrl))
                var postUrl = 'https://www2.fdic.gov/sod/SODSummary2.asp';
                //var postUrl = 'https://www2.fdic.gov/sod/SODSumReport.asp';
                request.post({ url: postUrl, formData: formData, jar: j }, function(err, res2) {
                    if(err) {
                        debug('res2:', err);
                    } else {
                        debug('--->', inspect(res2.body));
                        db.close()
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I also made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Jks15063/97eb7c735591565aa558) and here is [the repo](https://github.com/Jks15063/FDIC_scraper) if you feel like running the project

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if you print the results found by cheerio, each input query has two results.  Which was weird because when I skimmed through the html, I could only find one of each(one as_sfid and one as_fid).  Regardless, I decided to try all combinations, all of which give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke JS function submitReport() which is the onclick action defined for each of the anchor tags to emulate what the browser is doing and not do a direct post. Also I recommend that you use [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) vs. using plain request as Phantom JS is has full web stack which would be more realistic emulation of browser request.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try tonight. I was avoiding using Phantom because it adds a lot of complexity makes it more difficult to scrape pages in parallel (in my xp at least).